# using jquery after a marker event

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

i was working on a marker event and im trying to do a jquery code that modifies the css of a popup made with leaflet js.

the thing is that i want to access to an htlm tag of this popup from the marker event

for example if i have `<div><p id="myid">my text</p></div>`

Is there a way that I can use `myMarker.$("myid").css({font-size:"20px", backgroud-color:"#000"}).`

Im asking because  I have an array of markers and I need to edit these tags for only one of them.

thx for your time :)

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand your problem. Can you write more clearly example?

Comment: Cannot you just set a specific CSS rule? `#myid {font-size: 20px;}`

Comment: i tried like you say but nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  can use

```
var oldContent=myMarker.getPopup().getContent();

// oldContent is dom node object 
// you can check its id using $(oldContent).attr("id"); and perform your css change logic

var newContent=$(oldContent).css({font-size:"20px", backgroud-color:"#000"});
myMarker.getPopup().setContent(newContent[0]);
```

Comment: i have only one question. Why new content is an array variable?

Comment: Thats not an array. Its a jquery object. Jquery objects are like arrays but not exactly. they have indexed dom elements and and a couple of more fields. So to get the javascript native dom element which setcontent() function would accept we need to do newContent[0]. Setcontent content would not accept jquery object  it would only accept string or dom node object.

Comment: @RaúlNicolásCortésSantibañez If this solves your problem then please acknowledge my effort by accepting the answer. This keeps me motivated. If any doubt feel free to ask.

Comment: okay man thx a lot, i just wanted to now  why the structure you wrote. I didnt try yet because Im solving other things at same time but I now it will work, thank you a lot :)